# Ionic package build android not working

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I am trying to publish my app for Android and iOS using Ionic Cloud Package. When I do this I am successfully creating the .apk and .ipa but the app does not work on my device. However when I build the app for android using `ionic build --release` I am getting a working application. Why are these two methods behaving differently. I would like to use cloud Packaging. Because I do not have a mac. So Without it I cannot create an app for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) for Building in the cloud.
This method requires you to install [phonegap cli](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/).

Comment: This method is the same as ionic build which does not work for some reason.